# Path integral with boundary and bulk terms

Tags: path-integral

I was wondering if their is a general strategy for computing path integrals with a mix of boundary and bulk integral actions. Do people use divergence theorem to convert the action into bulk integrals, or is there some other trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual Feynman rules may still be derived. If there are both boundary fields and bulk fields, one needs to include the bulk-to-boundary propagators, too. The same problem has to be solved in the AdS/CFT correspodence. Search for "Witten diagrams" to see how the Feynman diagrams are ultimately done in this context.